# Scripting from Scala

Tags: scala, groovy, jruby, jython, rhino

I have a little project with an editor, some special need I had and which I hacked together in an afternoon. A co-worker looked over my shoulder (don't you hate that?) and said "Oh neat, but can it do X?"

So, to combine my ever-lasting need to learn new things and to enable some extensions on that little editor, I want to put some simple manipulation functions into there. And thus, I want to enable some scripting.

I found some tutorials about the [ScriptEngine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html), that is not the problem. The problem is that it seems only to support JavaScript via Rhino. I have them all installed via `apt-get`: JRuby, Jython, Groovy, but the ScriptEngine doesn't know them.

What I would prefer is dropping a dependency in my `build.sbt`. Maybe someone knows a way to do that properly?

And if I resume to JavaScript, can I safely assume Rhino is installed on every machine with a JDK?

Comment: You can safely assume Rhino is installed on every machine with a JDK version 6 or later (version 5 may also work)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about embedding a Scala interpreter.  This might be overkill for what you are doing, however.

http://suereth.blogspot.com/2009/04/embedding-scala-interpreter.html

You could also look at the scaladocs for an interpreter directly.

http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/package.html

If they are really simple manipulation functions, you could write your own language using parser combinators.

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-magic-behind-parser-combinators

Answer (score 0):

[Stir some Groovy into your Java apps](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg05245/) is a developerWorks tutorial which doesn't depend on ScriptEngine but instead uses `groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader` - I had been meaning to try adapting this to Scala but hadn't got round to it yet (let me know how it goes).

When adapting it to Scala, remember that:

```
ClassLoader parent = CLEmbedGroovy.class.getClassLoader();
```

is written:

```
val parent: ClassLoader = classOf[CLEmbedGroovy].getClassLoader()
```

Further down that article there are other interesting options such as `GroovyScriptEngine`. SBT-wise I think ([source](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/groovy/groovy-all-1.0-jsr/05)) you just need to drop in:

```
val groovyAll1.0Jsr = "groovy" % "groovy-all-1.0-jsr" % "05"
```

Good luck!